# PHP - Strict Standards: Accessing static property as non static - Nothing is static?

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm at a loss. I have gone over my two classes extensively for hours. Nothing is static, nothing is being statically referenced, yet I cannot get rid of this error.

**Class A's file (*ClassA.php*)**

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\A;

require_once "B.php";
use MyProject\B as B;

class A
{

    private $privateVariable;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $b = new B\B();
        $this->privateVariable = $b->something;

    }

}
```

**Class B's file (*B.php*)**

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\B;

class B
{

    public $something;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->something = "Some (dynamic) string value";

    }

}
```

I am not new to classes, however I've never had this issue before (without having at least a static variable or method or static reference).

---

**The errors I get are:**

> Strict Standards: Accessing static property MyProject\B\B::$something as non static in A.php on line (this line: `$this->privateVariable = $b->something`)

**and**

> Notice: Undefined property: MyProject\B\B::$something in  A.php on line (this line: `$this->privateVariable = $b->something`)

I think anyone reading this understands that I want to get B's variable `$something` into A's variable `$privateVariable` while maintaining class B as an instance within class A upon instantiation of class A like:

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\Something;

require_once "A.php";
use MyProject\A as A;

$a = new A\A()
// $a's private variable $privateVariable should be set to "Some (dynamic) string value"
```

Any help regarding this issue is greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT**
Changed code to better reflect original code (changing `use AS` to `use as` and changing the way use was calling the appropriate classes
**PHP Version: 5.6**

---

**EDIT 2**
I honestly have no idea what was going on.

- I uploaded my files to the server
- I then checked that they were uploaded properly
- I was still receiving those errors
- I then commented all my code except the lines above
- I still received the error
- I then uncommented the lines I had just commented out (using CTRL+Z)
- I then reuploaded the document
- I ensured that they were uploaded properly
- Now everything works.

I apologize for this issue but I think it was more of a bug than an actual code issue. I'll just blame Godaddy for this one (yes, I know Godaddy is great choice *sarcasm*)

Comment: Possible silly questions: Is this the whole code? Is there any sort of caching involved? What PHP version are you using? I just copy+pasted your code, ran it, and it works just fine. No errors involved.

Comment: PHP Version     ?             ?

Comment: Error is `non static in ClassB.php on line` why are you pointing to ClassA.php `$this->privateVariable =` ????? Show the original Error!

Comment: `ClassB.php on line (this line: $this->privateVariable = $b->something)` still wrong :)

Comment: I've added PHP Version and edited code to better reflect original code

Comment: Since this **isn't** the real code but just something you created to reflect it - it's super hard to tell you what's wrong since everything looks fine. The question is, are you looking at the right location at all? There's a common mistake that I discovered when developers can't figure out what's going on since they are editing completely wrong set of files.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I've changed the error to properly reflect the errors I'm receiving as well

Comment: `use MyProject\B as B;` that now not right!! ClassB missing :)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions you're not reading the code nor are you even attempting to understand the problem. If the class didn't exist, then the error wouldn't be about class property, it would be about the class not being there. Please, take a minute to absorb the issue first then provide help. This way we're just creating useless noise.

Comment: I just ran your code and received no error, warning or notice. I am set to display all errors and nothing showed up in the browser or the logs. By adding a `getPrivate(){return $this->privateVariable}` method on `A`, I was able to verify that `B`'s `something` property was properly set.  Don't know what's going on. Did anyone else try to replicate the issue?

Comment: @Mjh  I read it fully, and he reedit the post since then. And from the first time it worked. So if i ask for REAL line number, to take the errors/issues small and the hole post is reedited (with an Fatal Error class not found) than i point to that. Thank for your comment.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Yep that right. Here didn't show the real problem here, just `properly reflect the errors / code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, full working single file example:

```
namespace MyProject\ClassA {
    use MyProject\ClassB\B;
    class A {
        private $privateVariable;
        public function __construct() {
            $b = new B();
            $this->privateVariable = $b->something;
            print $this->privateVariable;
        }
    }
}
namespace MyProject\ClassB{
class B{
    public $something;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->something = "Some (dynamic) string value";
    }
}
}
namespace MyProject\Something {
    use MyProject\ClassA\A;
    $a = new A();
}
```

Test it.

Update:

You use :

```
 use MyProject\A as A;

 $a = new A\A();
```

But `use MyProject\A` point to a namespace not a class.

So this is right:

```
use MyProject\A\A as A;

$a = new A();
```

And another note use this : `use \MyProject\A\A`  with `\` at first place.

Comment: I tried to replicate the OP's error but couldn't.  Did you see any error or warnings?

Comment: I put everything into one large file like this and it runs. The moment I separate them into different files it fails. I'm pointing to all the files correctly

Comment: Nope, no errros at all.

Comment: @ctwheels  you can not use namespaces only , wait i update my post.

Comment: OK, you can use namespace only for `use` but also use then `\\` in your code at first place.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I edited my post. I have no idea what the actual issue was but I will change my use statements to reflect what you've presented above so that my code is a little more legible. Thank you. I'll mark your reply as the answer as I tested it using your code above and it worked, then did the steps I describe above in my second edit and everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

There's an observation worth noting: You don't write `use ... AS ...` you write `use ... as ...`. AS should be all lower cases. Therefore; the correct `use statement` should have read: `use MyProject\ClassB as cB`. The Code-Excerpt below will illustrate these points.

```
    <?php

        namespace MyProject;

        require_once "ClassB.php";
        use MyProject\B as cB;

        class A {

            private $privateVariable;

            public function __construct()   {
                $b = new cB();
                $this->privateVariable = $b->getSomething();
            }
        }
    ?>

    <?php

        namespace MyProject;

        class B{

            public $something;

            public function __construct(){
                $this->something = "Some (dynamic) string value";
            }

            // YOU MAY WANT TO CREATE A FUNCTION TO GET THE SOMETHING          
            public function getSomething(){
               return $this->something;
            }
        }
```

Or using aliasing....

```
    <?php

        namespace MyProject\ClassA;

        require_once "ClassB.php";
        use MyProject\ClassB as cB;

        class A {

            private $privateVariable;

            public function __construct(){
                $b = new cB\B();
                $this->privateVariable = $b->getSomething();

            }

        }
    ?>

    <?php

        namespace MyProject\ClassB;

        class B{

            public $something;

            public function __construct(){
                $this->something = "Some (dynamic) string value";

            }

            // YOU MAY WANT TO CREATE A FUNCTION TO GET THE SOMETHING          
            public function getSomething(){
               return $this->something;
            }

        }
```

To run the code (The First Example - without Aliasing):::

```
    <?php
        namespace MyProject\Something;
        use MyProject\A as A;

        require_once "A.php";
        require_once "B.php";        

        $a = new A();
        var_dump($a);

        // PRODUCES:::
        object(MyProject\A)[1]
            private 'privateVariable' => string 'Some (dynamic) string value' (length=27)
```

Test it out yourself [HERE](https://eval.in/608030).

Comment: That would be a case if and `autoloader`would be involed, as long as not the original code works. I have tested it.

Comment: From [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php): All versions of PHP that support namespaces support three kinds of aliasing or importing: aliasing a class name, aliasing an interface name, **and aliasing a namespace name**.  So there's nothing wrong with `new Alias\B();`

Comment: I've changed the code above to better reflect the original code and changed `AS` to `as`

Answer (score 0):

I think your namespaces are incorrect. My bet is PHP couldn't instantiate the class and assumed you were calling it statically. I cleaned up the namespaces and created one giant file and [it runs fine](https://3v4l.org/464G5)

```
namespace MyProject\ClassB;

class B
{
    public $something;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->something = "Some (dynamic) string value";
    }

    public function getStr() {
        echo $this->something;
    }
}

namespace MyProject\ClassA;
use \MyProject\ClassB\B as B;

class A
{
    private $privateVariable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $b = new B();
        $this->privateVariable = $b->something;
        $b->getStr();
    }
}

namespace MyProject\Something;
use \MyProject\ClassA\A as A;
$a = new A();
```

Comment: `I think your namespaces are incorrect` There where ok in the first place ;)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions From the original code I had to make several namespace changes